# How to get @sys entities in DialogFlow API?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-cx

I am writing a Page in DialogFlow CX Node js API. The page have a parameter that uses system entities for example **@sys.any**.

So publishing such information require ids of the resources from dialogFlow. I can use a custom entity Type by following the pattern: `projects/<projectId>/locations/<location>/agents/<agentId>/entityType/<entityTypeId>`.

But for System entity I use the pattern :
`projects/<projectId>/locations/<location>/agents/<agentId>/entityType/@sys.entityname`.

Eventually gets an ERROR:

`Entity type 'projects/chatbot-dev-356403/locations/europe-west2/agents/1cd671ea-1ec6-4b3f-90fa-4c754d0f9f47/entityTypes/@sys.any' of form parameter 'Improve' does not exist in the agent.`

How to call that system resource (entity) through API?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me in python

```
'projects/-/locations/-/agents/-/entityTypes/sys.any'
```

is set as entity type and id is set to any

```
name = 'projects/-/locations/-/agents/-/entityTypes/sys.any'
intent_parameter = Intent.Parameter(id='any', entity_type=name, is_list=False)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how this solution works